# Need help getting NextJS to acknowledge my rewrites configuration

Tags: proxy, next.js

To eliminate cors OPTIONS requests I want to proxy API calls through the Next.JS server. I've added this configuration change to my next.config.js file:

```js
const withImages = require("next-images");
const { environment } = require("./environments/environment");

module.exports = withImages({
  rewrites: async () => [
    { source: "/proxy/api/:match*", destination: `${environment.apiUrl}/:match*` },
  ],
});
```

I'm running next version 10.2.3 (latest at time of posting).

Calls to the back-end are performed through fetch within React components. In the browser dev tools I can see that the HTTP request is being performed. A request is sent out to "http://localhost:4200/proxy/api/user/me". It hits the Next server. But after that the Next server does not hit the API server. It responds immediately with a 404. It seems that it hasn't recognized the "rewrites" configuration at all.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with an outdated version of nx